# Comparing versions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, versioning, nosql

just wondering if anyone can come up with a smarter way to do this...

Let's say I have some documents in MongoDB with a version property, for example something like 
`{ ..., version: { major: 1, minor: 2, patch: 13 } }`, or `{ ..., version: "1.2.13" }` if it is easier.

**What's the easiest way to find all documents that have version X.Y.Z or above?** The way I'm doing it now is basically a huge $and clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first design is actually very good. The reason is because you can index the fields `major`, `minor` and `patch` for fast reads.

Querying the data is actually much easier than using the `$and` query. You can just use a basic query on matching fields:

e.g.

```
db.versions.find({major:1,minor:2,patch:20}) //give me documents of version 1.2.20
db.versions.find({major:1}) //give me all documents with major version 1
db.versions.find({major:1,minor:{$gte:2,$lte:5}}) //give me all documents of major version and minor versions between 2 and 5 inclusive.
```

You can create an index like

```
db.versions.ensureIndex({major:1,minor:1,patch:1})
```

The `$and` query is mainly for the case where you want to run a more complex query on the same field multiple times. For instance, if you want to get major versions 1 and 2, you can use `$and`.

`db.versions.find({major:1,major:2})` will actually only return documents with major version 2. However, `db.versions.find({a:$all:[1,2]})` would work too in this case. You should ideally avoid using `$and` when you can because it actually spawns multiple queries for each expression in the `$and` array and performs a union. This is much more expensive than the query samples I provided above.

Comment: That's what I thought too. The problem with this approach is that 1.0.0 is actually bigger than 0.10.1. In that case the query with $lte and $gte is actually dependent on the major (or minor) version.

For example, I would like to grab all documents 1.0.0 or below.

Comment: One query that would get all the documents 1.0.0 or below would be db.versions.find({major:{$lte:1}}). Since you broke out the fields, you can actually query them independently eg. db.versions.find({minor:$in[1,10]}) //give me all versions which have a minor version of 1 or 10.

Comment: I see. You will need to use $or using one expression to handle the immediate version and one to handle the rest. eg) version < 1.1.1 $or:[{major:1,minor:{$lte:1},patch:{$lte:1}},{major:{$lt:1}}]. version > 2.2.2: $or:[{major:2,minor:{$gte:2},patch:{$gte:2}},{major:{gt:2}}]. Alternatively, you could do a hybrid approach where you store major,minor,patch in separate fields for equality matches and another field for ranges (eg. (major*10000)+(minor*100)+patch)

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the easiest way. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a fixed number of digits for the version number and store it as a string, you should be able to use `$gte`.

```
"001.002.0013" > "001.002.0011" = true
"001.003.0013" > "001.002.0013" = true
"002.000.0000" > "001.002.0013" = true
"001.002.0012" > "001.002.0013" = false
"001.001.0013" > "001.002.0013" = false
```

Comment: This looks like good&simple solution