# mongo query for version(. seperated string) and find greater than some version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

for example, I have a document 'test'

```java
{
    id: 1,
    package: [
        {
            "name": "win",
            "version": "1.2.5.10"
        },
        {
            "name": "linux",
            "version": "10.5.5.10"
        }
    ]
}, {
    id: 2,
    package: [
        {
            "name": "win",
            "version": "2.5.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "linux",
            "version": "10.4.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find all the "name": "win", with version greater than 2.4

the output should look like:

```java
{
    id: 2,
    package: [
        {
            "name": "win",
            "version": "2.5.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "linux",
            "version": "10.4.3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you will have to store the segments seperately instead of a string as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770338/comparing-versions-in-mongodb).